# How to send Mail using PostMark SMTP server using Sytem.Net.Mail?

Tags: c#

How to send Mail using PostMark SMTP server using Sytem.Net.Mail ?

I don't want to use there API I have up and running code which was earlier using Gmail SMTP to send out my mails .But due to mass mailing I needed PostMark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look into their documentation?

http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-smtp.html

-It's all there, I think...

Comment: Thanks I was doing that my firewall was messing it up on 25 it worked on 2525.

Comment: Link may be outdated: try this: https://postmarkapp.com/send-email/net